# RouteUrl is null when generating url from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a paged search result set, which is generated in a partial view.

For generating the paging links I use this `UrlHelper` extension for keeping the current `RouteValues` and just merging with the provided route values.

```
public static string CurrentRouteUrl(this UrlHelper url, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    var context = url.RequestContext;
    var combinedRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(context.RouteData.Values);
    var queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

    foreach (var key in queryString.AllKeys.Where(key => key != null))
    {
        combinedRouteValues[key] = queryString[key];
    }

    if (routeValues != null)
    {
        foreach (var routeValue in routeValues)
        {
            combinedRouteValues[routeValue.Key] = routeValue.Value;
        }
    }

    return url.RouteUrl(routeName, combinedRouteValues);
}
```

Usage (example):

`@Url.CurrentRouteUrl("MyRouteName", new RouteValueDictionary { { "Query.Page", 10 } }`

But for some reason the returned url is `null`, when rendering from the partial view.

If I use the default `Url.RouteUrl(...)` provided by the MVC framework, the url is not null. But this method does not preserve the current query-string.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the url context in my extension method, but I am at a loss at the moment. Any feedback welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer the question myself. This line:

```
var combinedRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(context.RouteData.Values);
```

Sat the `routeName` which I tried to override in the method signature, the fix is to remove the `context.RouteData.Values` from that constructor, because I wish to provide the `routeName` and not use the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you invoking it from a controller? Your assumption is correct, you probably do not have the context. Try only for testing porposes, invoking this method from a controller.

The call yould be like this:

```
CurrentRouteUrl(Url, "routeName", "routeValues")
```

Where Url is just Url like passed above, just pass it to the method like that, it's a property from System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Best

Daniel